# What is the value of $i^0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have to solve the following question -

$$\sum_{n=0}^{1000} i^n$$

where $i = \sqrt{-1}$

To be able to solve the problem, I need to know the value of $i^0$. What is the value of $i^0$? Is it 0 or indeterminate or something else?

Comment: $\forall z\in\Bbb{C}-\{0\},z^0=1$

Comment: By the way: I would not use $i := \sqrt{-1}$ as a definition of $i$.

Comment: We want a definition of $i^0$ that is consistent with $z^n\cdot z^m=z^{n+m}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $z\neq 0$. This leads us to $i^0i=i^0i^1=i^{0+1}=i^1=i$ so $i^0$ must equal...

Comment: You've tagged this question with the five most popular tags site-wide, most of which have nothing to do with the question. I see that you've also done this on all of your previous questions. Please read tag descriptions and only use relevant tags.

Comment: $i^0=e^{0\ln(i)}=e^{0i\pi/2}=e^0=1$.

Comment: @LeBtz then would you define it as **the Principle square root of $-1$**? :)

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: No, I would introduce $\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb R^2$ (as vectorspace over $\mathbb R$) and then define a multiplication on it. Then I would define $i := (0,1)$ and from there on write complex numers as linear combinations of the basis $1,i$. It's surely possible using field extensions aswell but I don't know what a good definition would be in this context. Though, it's certainly not $\sqrt{-1}$ which isn't well defined at that point. Something like the principle root doesn't even exist before defining complex numbers.

Comment: @LeBtz: If $R$ is any ring and $a \in R$ is any element, then $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is defined to be some element in some ring extension of $R$ which satisfies $\sqrt[n]{a}^n=a$. In many cases, the choice of the root is irrelevant because the automorphism group of the extension exchanges them. This is the case in particular for $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$  (which you can define as $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$, for instance) and $\sqrt{-1}$ (which is then either chosen as $[X]$ or $[-X]$, doesn't matter).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Ok, before, I thought it might be a problem that you have multiple elments $x$ of $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$. which satisfy $x^2 = -1$, which makes it not a good definition to just pick one of them, since different people could pick a different $i$. But that doesn't matter so much because the obtained structures are just the same, right?

Comment: @LeBtz: Right. That, as far as I understand it, is the basis of Galois theory.

Comment: Empty product anyone???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the same approach as with (one-dimensional) real numbers:

$i^3=-i$

$i^2=-1$

$i^1=i$

To go up the list above, multiply by $i$. To go down the list, we do the opposite and divide by $i$. $i^0$, then, must logically be the next element below, which means

$i^0=\frac{i^1}{i}=1$

Comment: Good and simple explanation. Plus one.

Comment: I've been using this explanation for the reals for beginners for years; I'm worried it doesn't translate perfectly for complex numbers, given how alien $i$ can seem initially. I'm wary that $\frac{i}{i}=1$ might not be totally obvious to a first-timer--if "any number to the 0 power is 1" didn't translate readily for OP to $\mathbb{C}$, it stands to reason that "any number divided by itself is 1" failed to translate as well. But I'm not sure how to get around that.

Answer (score 5):

In every multiplicative group $G$ we define
$$
g^0=e
$$
for every $g\in G$. In this case we have $G=\mathbb C^*$

One can use the definition $z^a=e^{a\log(z)}$, in this case we defined $\log(z)$ for all complex numbers except negative real numbers. And $e^z$ is defined for every $z\in\mathbb C$, so by this definition we have
$$
i^0=1
$$

Comment: OP could be confused about $e$ here if they haven't studied group theory. Here $e$ means the identity element for the group operation and not the base of the natural logarithm.

Comment: Maybe, but this definition comes from group theory...

Comment: If the OP hasn't studied group theory...then s/he is probably not aware of what a group *is*.

Comment: Sometimes you can tell the level of _OP_'s knowledge by the way they ask. Sometimes not. In general **I think** (I agree it is subjective) the best way is to propose a solution, which uses mostly related terms, based on what _OP_ wrote. After that it is good (personally I really like those answer) to add maybe something more general, such that the _OP_ question is only special case - as in this example.

Comment: One can use the definition $z^a=e^{a\log(z)}$, in this case we defined $\log(z)$ for all complex numbers except negative real numbers. And $e^z$ is defined for every $z\in\mathbb C$

Comment: Why do you exclude negative real numbers? As far as I know the complex logarithm is defined everywhere except $0$

Comment: I used to define the complex logarithm on a domain such that is continuous...you may define it everywhere except origin...

Comment: I would say this is clearly too high-level for the question posed--a bazooka to kill a chicken.

Comment: Yes...:) of course...

Comment: I wonder why neutral elements of groups are not just always denoted by $1$ (in the multiplicative written case).

Comment: z^a=e^alog(z). What sorcery is this?

Answer (score 4):

We have $x^0:= 1$ for *every* complex number $x$. (Notice that this is the only convention which fits into the rules of arithmetic, and there is no need to exclude $x=0$. Think about the binomial theorem, for instance.)

By the way, your exercise $\sum_{n=0}^{1000} i^n$ can be solved with the usual formula for geometric series. Thus, it is $\dfrac{i^{1001}-1}{i-1}$ and now you can simplify this using $i^k = i^{k \bmod 4}$.

Comment: Note that there's an exception for x=0.

Comment: There is no exception. $0^0=1$ follows from the general definition $x^0=1$, which is the only sensible definition.

Comment: 0^0 is usually taken to be undefined (despite the fact that the limit of x^x as x ----> 0 is 1).

Comment: People who claim that $0^0$ is not defined haven't understood how mathematics works. There are plenty of them, I know, and they distribute their "ideas".

Comment: It is also a usual misconception that you can "work out" values of, say, $x^0$, by using the rules of arithmetic. It's vice versa. First, one defines expressions, and then one proves the rules.

Comment: Are you trying to say that people who leave $0^0$ undefined are cranks?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If we go back to Euler representation, what does $0e^0$ evaluate to?

Comment: Think about $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}$ and its validity for $a=0$.

Comment: Also, if you say you can define 0^0 by considering x^0 as x--->0, what happens if we instead consider 0^x as x--->0?

Comment: As you have just seen, it doesn't make any sense to motivate a definition of this expression via limits, because it is ambiguous. Instead, $x^0:=1$ is a definition which works (and is universally accepted) in every algebraic structure which contains a multiplication map (formally, a binary operation, written multiplicatively) and a multiplicative unit. More generally, one defines $x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x^0:=1$ is the recursive start. This definition can be applied, in particular, to complex numbers, and no case distinction is necessary.

Comment: I might mention that, it $f$ and $g$ are analytic, positive in some neighborhood of $0$, and $\lim_{x\to0}f=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0}g=0$, then $\lim_{x\to0}f^g=1$. Fairly certain.

Comment: I don't see why people get so caught up in the binomial theorem "argument" for $0^0 = 1$. In the binomial theorem, $a^k$ should be interpreted as number of functions from a set of cardinality $a$ to a set of cardinality $k$. (For integer $a$).

Comment: @user157227: That's also my favorite argument for defining $a^b$ for arbitrary natural numbers $a,b$ (including zero, of course), for sure! For every set $X$, there is a unique map $\emptyset \to X$. Hence, we must define $x^0=1$.

Comment: It is quite funny (sad?) that my answer has (currently) 5 downvotes and therefore gets "faded", and even gets probably more downvotes by people who think that they have to downvote my answer even more because potentially wrong answers have to be "punished" somehow. But: I know what I am writing about. I have a PhD mathematics, and have seen all these arguments by people who let $0^0$ undefined, and I have seen even more arguments by people who define $0^0=1$ and these arguments have convinced me. And probably they will also convince you once you open yourself to them. Think before downvoting!

Comment: That beid said, it really gets me nervous that the voting system on math.SE (and therefore, also on other sites) doesn't promote objectively correct answers, but only popular answers, and that popular answers can be plainly wrong. I have even given counterexamples for answers on mathoverflow which have been accepted answers for 3 years or so. You really cannot believe that vote counter there, you always should check things for yourself, if you can.

Comment: One should campare to $0\cdot \infty := 0$ in measure theory. I don't understand why nobody has a problem with this one. It's almost the same, it makes sense in almost all situations so it's defined that way. Nothing different here. Of course there are exceptions where the definition doesn't make sense, but it's easier to handle these exceptions manually.

Comment: @LeBtz That only works with a _countable infinity_, I believe. Not for an uncountable infinity (ex: $[0,1]$ is uncountably many points, measure $1$) or a potential infinity (ex: $\lim_{x\to0}x^2\frac1{x^2}$). (_Potential infinity_ being the type used for limits.) EDIT: Forget what I said about uncountable infinity. Pretty sure that cardinal multiplication gives $0\mathfrak c=0$. Though in the context of measure theory…

Comment: (+1) For what it's worth, your comments here made me realize I'm firmly in the $0^{0} = 1$ camp, even though I've stringently avoided admitting this in front of calculus students....

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I voted this down because of the insistence that both $0^0=1$ **and** that no disagreement is reasonable.  If this answer were edited to recognize that some people disagree (so that people aren't surprised when their math teacher says "$0^0\neq 1$"), I would change my downvote to an upvote.  (Even if the edit were to say something like "certain people do not consider $0^0=1$, but this doesn't make sense because of [reasons].")

Comment: In fact, no disagreement is reasonable. It is possible, and everyone can have his/her own opinion, but for this discussion only mathematical reasonable opinions should be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

For any complex number $z\not = 0$, we have $z^0 = 1$. There are two reasons:

1) By definition, a nonzero complex number $z = re^{i\theta}$ has $z^n = r^n e^{i n\theta}$ for any integer $n$. Note that since $z\not = 0$, the value of $\theta$ is determined modulo $2\pi$. (In fact, the reason that this definition only works for $n$ an integer is that $\theta$ is only defined modulo $2\pi$. Then $2\pi n$ is also a multiple of $2\pi$, so $r^n e^{in\theta}$ is still well-defined: $e^{in\theta} = e^{in(\theta + 2\pi)}$.) This definition works perfectly well for $n = 0$.

2) We want $z^{n+m} = z^n z^m$ for integers $n, m$ and $z\not = 0$. In particular, we want $z = z^{1+0} = z^0 z^1 = (z^0) z$, which holds iff $z^0 = 1$. Again, this argument works for any nonzero complex $z$, including $z = i$.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you know Euler's representation of complex numbers:
$$i:=e^{i\pi/2}$$
So...

---

EDIT: There is no recursive definition here.  Euler's representation $re^{i\theta}$ refers to the point $(r,\theta)$ (expressed in the polar coordinate system) on the complex plane, and hence you can well forget the square root definition when you work within Euler's system.

---

EDIT 2: And if you are seeking the reason why the two ways of defining $i$ are equivalent, you could grasp a shallow perspective by taking a glance at the Dimov's formula. But, as to the deep reason behind that,  I have to confess, it's beyond what I could tell.

---

EDIT 3: Ultimately, you have to understand that $i^0=1$ is also a **definition** (as is pointed out in that group theory answer). We define it this way so as to make the notation of the computation of complex numbers as compatible with what we do within real numbers as possible.

Comment: Actually you can see this fact from various perspectives. Euler's formula is only one of the examples.

Comment: You define $i$ via $i$? Really?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. No. It's not a recursive definition. It just means: $i$ sits at the point (0,1) on a complex plane.  Of course you can define $i$ as sqrt root of -1 if you please, but that's just different ways of definition. I use Euler's form just in order to let the OP see  $i^0=1$ more easily.

Answer (score -1):

From the rules of indices $i^{0}=1$

Comment: And now show the OP, the rules of Indices.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem not necessary, thanks.

Answer (score -4):

$$i^0=i^{1-1}=\frac{i^1}{i^1}=\frac ii$$
Now, $\frac ii$ is asking us for the number $c$ such that $c\times i=i$. It's not hard to show that $c=1$ is the only one that works. Thus, $\frac ii=1$, and:
$$i^0=1$$
(This exact argument shows that $z^0=1$ for *any* nonzero number $z$.)

Comment: This is nonsense, since you cannot work with powers etc. before defining them. $z^0:=1$ is a *definition*.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg When you first learned about exponents, in grade school, they defined it as _repeated multiplication_. Only later did they show you that this must mean that $z^0=1$. Now, when working with the foundations of mathematics, mathematicians have tried to find rigorous definitions that match what they think exponentiation _should_ mean, and thus they defined it using $z^0=1$ and recursion. But that's kind of artificial. Though it's more rigorous, when learning exponents for the first time, nobody learns about them like that.

Comment: Yes this is senseless. The condition is not symmetric. You assumed that $$i^{-1}=\frac{1}{i}$$ but you have to show first that how $$i^0=1$$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw No, it's not more rigorous: to the contrary, it's arbitrary and wrong to use laws of exponents before proving them (which *requires* defining $z^0=1$).

Comment: @SufyanNaeem All I've assumed is $a^{b-c}=\frac{a^b}{a^c}$.

Comment: @egreg I said that what Martin was suggesting is the more rigorous one.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Which means, by the way, that you assumed $a^0=1$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, the notion $$a^0=1, a\neq 0$$ gives us the idea that $$a^n=\frac{1}{a^{-n}}$$. This is what I say the deduction from a fundamental law: $a^0=1, a\neq 0$

Comment: @SufyanNaeem When people learn exponents the first time, I'm fairly certain that they're taught the rule for $a^{b-c}$ first, and _then_ use that rule to prove the ones about $a^0$ and $a^{-n}$. This isn't a course on foundations.

Comment: Yes and I was taught as same but this is still wrong. I restate, "The conditions are not symmetric". Be careful.

Comment: See the comment from Jp McCarthy

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Of course you can simply tell the OP "That's a definition".  But I'm afraid that won't help the OP comprehend, or at least, remember this *definition*.